# how to create an index in mongoengine to be unique=True and sparse=True

Tags: indexing, unique, mongoengine, sparse-matrix

I am using mongoengine with flask. I have a db.Document class called profile in which i want a field to be nullable and unique, i understand the way to do this is to make an index of that field that is both sparse=True and unique=True, how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will have to declare the index in the `meta` definition eg:

```
class BlogPost(Document):
    date = DateTimeField(db_field='addDate', default=datetime.now)
    category = StringField()
    tags = ListField(StringField())

    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['-date'], 'unique': True,
              'sparse': True, 'types': False },
        ],
    }
```

Comment: What does the 'types' key specify for an index in the example above?

Comment: @J-bob It doesn't exist according to [mongoengine docs](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html)

Answer (score 10):

In case of unique constraint you can set it with the field declaration as:

```
email = mongodb.EmailField(required=True, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

We can directly mention it in the Field parameters. Example:

```
email = db.EmailField(sparse=True, unique=True, required=False)
```

Comment: What do I have to import to use `db.EmailField(...)`?